# Cloudera Manager Express Wizard Does Not Detect EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am attempting to install Cloudera Manager on an EC2 instance following these [directions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.6.2/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_on_EC2.html). They indicate that once I have installed Manager and navigated to the EC2 host page at port 7180, it will automatically detect that it is running on an EC2 instance and allow me to have it deploy and configure my hadoop cluster. The docs mention an EC2 related warning message on the welcome screen. Instead I get a different welcome screen that doesn't mention EC2:

[image: Welcome Screen]

When I click continue I get a second screen where I am required to enter the name or ip of existing hosts:

[image]

So it appears that the express wizard doesn't detect that it is running on EC2. Does anyone know why this might be occurring?

Comment: Hello, were you able to find out what happened? I'm having the same issue. I suspect it's because I'm not using a public ip on that instance but I'm not sure. Is there a way to force this Cloud Wizard to show up? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, no, I wasn't able to get it up and running and I ended up not using cloudera.