# Install Cloudera on 3 AWS EBS EC2 Instance

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudera-manager

I have posted a similar question earlier but answers to that 
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068661/changing-ip-address-for-cloudera-in-ec2-ebs-instance)  didn't help me .

I want to setup a three node Hadoop cluster on AWS using cloudera . I have refereed several links where there is step by step guide how to step these clusters :

[Link1](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_on_EC2.html,)

[Link2](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-create-a-cdh-cluster-on-amazon-ec2-via-cloudera-manager/)

I all these links the step mentioned i have tried but since these installtion are done [Instance Stored based Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html). I dont have an option to stop these instances one installation is completed only option to (rebbot/terminate) . I have also tried launching three EBS based instance first and then started installation one of them then tried to add the other two instances while installation like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642791/cloudera-manager-express-wizard-does-not-detect-ec2) . But it doesn't detect the other two instances as this data node and I am not sure what other approach to use . Any answers in this regard is would be really helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Specify Private IPs for the hosts to install Cloudera Agent on.